# Prevent Trace from including package functions

Tags: packages

Suppose `` MyApp`Func1 `` is a function inside the package `MyApp`.  How do I prevent `Trace[Func1[x]]` from displaying everything inside `Func1` (or what's inside any `MyApp` functions)?

`` SetAttributes[MyApp`Func1, {ReadProtected, Locked}] `` appears to do the job. but then I can't modify options of `Func1` with `SetOptions`.

Comment: What do want `Trace[Func1[x]]` to display if not the functions that are called inside it? After all, that's what `Trace` is for.

Comment: Why can't you? Unless you set it `Protected` there should be no problem.

Comment: It sounds like you know the solution: use a different public Symbol for the Options, and pass those to the `Locked` function that you don't want read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the [`TraceOff`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraceOff) option:

```
Func1[x_] := 2+2
Trace[Func1[x], TraceOff->_Func1]
```

> {Func1[x],4}

If you want to kill off tracing of a whole package, you could use something like:

```
Trace[expr, TraceOff -> (h_[___] /; Context[h]==="MyApp`")]
```

Comment: That is very helpful.  Do you know how to use the related `$TraceOff` symbol?  I tried setting it to the pattern you suggested, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Doing `$TraceOff=patt; Trace[expr]` will not work because `Trace` sets `$TraceOff` to `None` (the default value of `TraceOff`).